# Are двусторонний and двухсторонний completely interchangeable?

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова, правописание

Are **двусторонний** and **двухсторонний** just two valid versions of the same word or are there slight differences?

If the former is the case, which version, if any, is considered more formal/more modern/more correct etc?

If the latter is the case, what are the differences? Are there any phrases or situations that accept exclusively or preferably one version over the other?

In [this thread](http://www.gramota.ru/forum/kurilka/79684/) of gramota.ru one person argues that *двухсторонний* is more appropriate to use in the meaning of *having two sides*, whereas *двусторонний* has the meaning of *mutual*. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numeral *два* in old Russian was declined in such called dual number, now lost:

```
два
дву
двома
дву
двома
о два
два
```

Later, with the loss of dual number, its declension paragidm changed to that of demonstrative pronouns in plural, with the base form taken from the old genitive:

```
два (те)
дву-х (тех)
дву-м (тем)
дву-х (тех)
дву-мя (теми)
о дву-х (о тех)
```

The instrumental case got contaminated with the old declension paradigm (and has also contaminated the inst. of *три* and *четыре*: *тремя*, *четырьмя*).

Both the old (*дву-*) and the new (*двух-*) genitives remained productive for complex words, however in the modern language there is a trend to use *двух-* for new words. In words which allow both forms, the old form *дву-* is usually perceived as a high style, formal version.

Rosenthal in *Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию* advices:

> Равноправны варианты сложных слов, в состав которых входит элемент: *дву-* /*–двух-*, например: *двуголосный – двухголосный, двудонный – двухдонный, двуклассный – двухклассный, двулетний – двухлетний, двупольный – двухпольный, двускатный – двухскатный, двусложный – двухсложный, двустволка – двухстволка, двусторонность – двухсторонность.*
>
> Сложные слова *двубортный, двуглавый, двугривенный, двуединый, двужильный, двузначный, двузубец, двуколка, двукратный, двуличный, двуперстие, двурогий, двусмысленный, двустопный, двууглекислый, двучлен, двуязычный* и некоторые др. не допускают вариантов написания с *двух-*.
>   Но основной массив таких сложных слов пишется с элементом *двух-*: *двухатомный, двухгодичный, двухкамерный, двухлетие, двухместный, двухпалубный, двухпроцентный, двухслойный, двухсотлетний, двухсуточный, двухтактный, двухтомный, двухчасовой, двухцветный, двухэтажный* и др.
>
> Разграничительную роль играет фонетико-орфоэпическое отличие: перед гласными (в том числе йотированными), как правило, употребляется *двух-* во избежание стечения двух гласных, например: *двухактный, двухосный, двухъярусный, двухэлементный*, но имеются отступления: *двуокись, двууглекислый, двуязычие* и некоторые др.

Answer (score 5):

Both of these are grammatically correct, although many Russian language teachers consider form *двусторонний*, "more correct".

**Большой толковый словарь:**

> ДВУСТОРОННИЙ; ДВУХСТОРОННИЙ.
>
> 1. Имеющий две стороны; происходящий, производимый, расположенный и т. п. с двух сторон. Двустороннее воспаление лёгких. Двухстороннее
>      уличное движение. //С одинаковыми сторонами, без изнанки и лица (о
>      ткани). Д. драп.
> 2. Обязательный для обеих сторон; обоюдный. Двухстороннее соглашение. Двусторонний договор. // Действующий в обе стороны. Двусторонняя
>      радиосвязь.

The fact that these two words are given in the dictionary on one line together means that the words are totally interchangeable.  Yet, considering these two meanings:

1. Having two sides.  In this meaning, both words are used equally and interchangeably.
2. Mandatory for two sides, coming from both sides, or working both ways as in *двусторонний договор* or *двусторонняя связь*.  While, again, both words are grammatically correct, more often than not, *двусторонний* is used in formal writing.

Finally, it's worth noting that there are set phrases that use one word or the other, for example, *двухстороннее соглашение* and *двухстороннее движение*, but *двусторонняя связь* and *двусторонние переговоры*.  The reason one or the other word is used has more to do with the way it historically been used rather than for any technical or grammatical reason.